# python division with large numbers automatically ceiled

Tags: python, division

```
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print(111111111111111111/10)
1.1111111111111112e+16
>>> print(int(111111111111111111/10))
11111111111111112
>>>
```

Refering to the above snippet, Can someone please help me understand why `111111111111111111/10` returns `11111111111111112` instead of `11111111111111111`?

Comment: `11111111111111111.0 == 11111111111111112.0`. Floating point is wild. Use `//` for precise integer division, though.

Comment: @Ry- so i guess, `math.floor()` and others wont help as well in such cases?

Comment: Correct. If you have two integers and want to divide them for an exact result, you have to use `//`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [floor division](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/floor_division.html):

```
>>> 111111111111111111//10
11111111111111111
>>>
```